# Javascript : Get date in yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me how do i get the date in YYYY-MM-DD format ?

I tried the below

```
var a = new Date();
console.log(a);
```

But it comes out as

```
Fri Dec 01 2017 11:45:04 GMT+1100 (Local Daylight Time)
```

Comment: i have one word for your regarding dates in javascript, [momentJS](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: [a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate()].join('-');

Comment: google is your friend